# react state initialisation conditional

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a class based component in React-Native where I am initialising few state variables inside the constructor -

```
constructor(props)
{

this.state={{
   variable1:0,
   variable2:0
   variable3: this.state.variable1.length>1 && this.state.variable2.length >1 //Will show error
}}

}
```

I am trying to initialize variable3 based on the values of variable1 and 2. The current approach will not work as state is not initialized yet.
What is the best alternative to do this?

Please let me know if I can explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When that line starts executing, `this.state` doesn't exist. So you can't access `this.state.variable1` to get a value. There are several ways you could do it. For example, create local variables, then use those:

```
const var1 = 0;
const var2 = 0;
this.state = {
  variable1: var1,
  variable2: var2,
  variable3: var1 > 1 && var2 > 1
}
```

Or create an incomplete state object, then add more to it:

```
this.state = {
  variable1: 0,
  variable2: 0,
}
this.state.variable3 = this.state.variable1 > 1 && this.state.variable2 > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your value in state then rather than using a variable outside of the state then use the lifecycle methods to keep track of state changes:

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-worker-nvjod?fontsize=14

In this example I am tracking the 3 vars in state:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    variable1: 1,
    variable2: 2,
    variable3: 0
  };
}
```

Then when the Component mounts I run `setState()` to update the value of `variable3` and use `setTimeout` to then update the value of `variable1` after 3 seconds.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { variable1, variable2 } = this.state;
  this.setState({ variable3: variable1 + variable2 });
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ variable1: 3 });
  }, 3000);
}
```

If you have a variable outside of state this change will not be reflected in your rendered output, however using `componentDidUpdate()` you can check if the state has updated and again use `setState()` to update `variable3` which will render to the screen.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { variable1, variable2, variable3 } = this.state;
  if (
    variable1 !== prevState.variable1 ||
    variable2 !== prevState.variable2
  ) {
    this.setState({ variable3: variable1 + variable3 });
  }
}
```

Finally render all three state vars:

```
render() {
  const { variable1, variable2, variable3 } = this.state;
  return (
    <>
      <p>variable1: {variable1}</p>
      <p>variable2: {variable2}</p>
      <p>variable3: {variable3}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```